# ADE7953 smart energy metering - how to connect it

Tags: microcontroller, current-measurement, energy, power-meter, power-measurement

I am currently looking for a IC that would allow me to aggregate energy metering data in my house. I came upon ADE7953 chip from Analog Devices but there is no info how to connect it with power source like power socket. I would be really gratefull if you could help me with that and show me the way. Any schematics, current, voltage sensors needed will be priceless.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that the ADE7953 would be hard work as a starting point.

Suggest you look at this [web site](https://shop.openenergymonitor.com/).

The Open Energy Monitor provides all the information you could desire for your project, you can build or buy depending on how keen you are to do your own development.
Their compute solutions are based primarily on Arduino and Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Well, it's not supposed to be easy after all :) I have already build optic head for reading electro meters, profile data,  Billing data etc. now I want to build something very compact. So I could place it in every power socket of my house and see where this energy goes and stuff :) have you ever worked with that chip?

Comment: No I have not worked with it, though I did look at it before I built my front end acquisition. Good luck.